# sql : Create a table IN a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i'm trying to create some tables in a tables IN SQL, but i'm a bit confused and not too good in SQL.

I would like to have something like that, please :

Category (Table) -> Dev (Table having an ID) -> PHP, JS, C, .. (Values)

[Representation Wanted to do this in HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weCPI.png)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What you want is relationships between tables not a table in a table. Because this is not possible in RDBMS

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: I'm using MYSQL sorry, jarlh,
And do you know how i can do relationships between tables, examples on the internet are a bit confusing for me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@steph-57 You can create multiple tables.

For Example :-

1-Category Table - (Id, CategoryName) 
2-Category Sub value Table - (Id, CategoryId,Value) - Category Id should be associated with Category Table's Id column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I have to create a primary key "ID" in the category table, and then in the "sub"table a foreign key "CategoryID" , right?